# Group by automatically adds name space attribute

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <ns0:SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSyncMsg xmlns:iwsc="http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/invoicewebservicecomponents/v0.1" xmlns:ns0="http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSync/v0.1">
      <ns0:Data>
        <ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope>2016-11-02</ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope>
      </ns0:Data>
    </ns0:SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSyncMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to accomplish it with following query.
The problem arises on the `ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope` node. Name space gets added as an attribute there. Which it shouldn't.

What causes it is adding "group by 0" in my select. If I remove it then the namespace attribute doesn't get declared. But I will have some grouping in production code so I can't just remove it.

```
SELECT
  xmlroot (
xmlelement ("soapenv:Envelope",
xmlattributes ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "xmlns:soapenv"),
xmlelement (
"soapenv:Body",
xmlattributes (
'id-1' AS "wsu:Id",
'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' AS "xmlns:wsu"),
xmlelement (
"ns0:SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSyncMsg",
xmlattributes (
'http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/invoicewebservicecomponents/v0.1' AS "xmlns:iwsc",
'http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSync/v0.1' AS "xmlns:ns0"),
xmlelement ("ns0:Data",
xmlagg (
xmlelement (
"ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope", sysdate)
)
)
)
)
),
VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8') "XmlRoot"
FROM dual
GROUP BY 0;
```

This query outputs following xml. Notice the `ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope` node and added namespace attribute.

**Wrong output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <ns0:SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSyncMsg xmlns:iwsc="http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/invoicewebservicecomponents/v0.1" xmlns:ns0="http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSync/v0.1">
      <ns0:Data>
        <ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope xmlns:ns0="http://fina.hr/eracun/b2b/SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSync/v0.1">2016-11-02</ns0:B2BOutgoingInvoiceEnvelope>
      </ns0:Data>
    </ns0:SendB2BOutgoingInvoiceSyncMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```